# $(H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3 \cong H_1 \otimes H_2 \otimes H_3 \cong H_1 \otimes (H_2 \otimes H_3)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let $H_1, H_2, H_3$ be Hilbert spaces. In this post, $\odot$ denotes an algebraic tensor product and $\otimes$ a tensor product of Hilbert spaces (i.e. a completion of an algebraic tensor product w.r.t. the canonical inner product). I want to show that $$(H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3 \cong H_1 \otimes H_2 \otimes H_3 \cong H_1 \otimes (H_2 \otimes H_3)$$
if this is even true?

I tried the following:

The canonical map $$\psi: H_1 \odot H_2 \odot H_3 \to (H_1 \odot H_2) \odot H_3$$
is easily checked to be isometric. Hence, $\psi$ extends to an isometry $$\psi: H_1 \otimes H_2 \otimes H_3 \to (H_1\otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$$
and since $(H_1 \odot H_2)\odot H_3 $ is dense in $(H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$, $\psi$ is surjective. Hence, we have an isometric isomorphism, as desired.

The other isomorphism can be shown similarly.
Is the above correct?

Comment: What's your definition of the triple algebraic tensor product?

Comment: @Christoph The universal property that turns trilinear maps into linear maps on the tensor product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have an isometry between two pre-Hilbert spaces $A$ and $B$, you know that the resulting Hilbert spaces $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are isometric as well, since your isometry will canonically extend to the completions.

However, the Hilbert space $(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3$ is by definition the completion of the pre-Hilbert space $(H_1\otimes H_1)\odot H_3$, not of $(H_1\odot H_2)\odot H_3$.

Hence, what you need to check is that going from $(H_1\odot H_2)\odot H_3$ to $(H_1\otimes H_2)\odot H_3$ by completing the first factor and then to $(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3$ by completing the result yields a Hilbert space that is canonically isometric to what you get from directly completing the pre-Hilbert space $(H_1\odot H_3)\odot H_3$.

So, in your attempt, the extension of $\psi$ to completions should be
$$
\overline \psi \colon \underbrace{H_1\otimes H_2\otimes H_3}_{= \overline{H_1\odot H_2\odot H_3}} \stackrel{\cong}\longrightarrow \overline{(H_1\odot H_2)\odot H_3}
$$
and you are missing an isometry
$$
\overline{(H_1\odot H_2)\odot H_3} \cong \underbrace{(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3}_{=\overline{\left(\overline{H_1\odot H_2}\right)\odot H_3}}.
$$

---

See Proposition 2.6.5 in R.V. Kadison, J. R. Ringrose: *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras* (1983) for a general proof of
$$H_1\otimes \dots \otimes H_{n+m} \cong (H_1\otimes \dots\otimes H_n)\otimes(H_{n+1}\otimes\dots\otimes H_{n+m})$$
using a universal property of tensor products of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks! How can I obtain this last isometry?

Comment: Are you sure this answer is correct, it looks like you claim $(H_1 \odot H_2)\otimes H_3\cong (H_1\otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$ in your last paragraph which seems a bit weird?

Comment: Well, what's your definition of the triple Hilbert space tensor product? I assumed it was the completion of the triple algebraic tensor product, so only one completion step involved. In $(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3$ you have two completion steps, so if you want to show that's isomorphic to the triple tensors product, you have to show that completing $H_1\odot H_2$ first doesn't matter when you complete again in the end, right?

Comment: If instead you just define $H_1\otimes H_2\otimes H_2$ as $(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3$ and show this is isometric to $H_1\otimes(H_2\otimes H_3)$, this problem goes away.

Comment: I define $H_1 \otimes H_2 \otimes H_3$ as the Hilbert space completion of $H_1 \odot H_2 \odot H_3$ (with the trilinear maps) with respect to the canonical inner product on this space.

Comment: I just don't get how you get the last isometry in your answer. Please elaborate.

Comment: I didn't work out the details (or if this is even true using non-iterated tensor products). I just wanted to point out a flaw in your argument.

Comment: Using the [universal property involving Hilbert–Schmidt mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces#Universal_property) might be a better approach.

Comment: You are not sure if the theorem statement is true? That's possible, because I could not find this result online. I hope at least $H_1 \otimes (H_2\otimes H_3)  \cong (H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$ is true?

Comment: Sadly I'm not familiar with that universal property. I believe if the statement is true then an elementary approach should be possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure it's true using triple algebraic tensor products and a single completion, but I would guess it is. The statement $H_1 \otimes (H_2\otimes H_3)  \cong (H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$ is listed in the German Wikipedia without citation, but I can't give you a good reference.

Comment: Well, here is one: Proposition 2.6.5 in R.V. Kadison, J. R. Ringrose: *Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras*, 1983.

Comment: Thanks. That definitely settles that $H_1 \otimes (H_2 \otimes H_3) \cong (H_1 \otimes H_2) \otimes H_3$, yet the original question still stands so if you don't mind I will wait some more to award the bounty/accept the answer (I already upvoted earlier).

Comment: It also settles the case with a triple product, since it shows $H_1\otimes \dots \otimes H_{n+m} \cong (H_1\otimes \dots\otimes H_n)\otimes(H_{n+1}\otimes\dots\otimes H_{n+m})$.

Comment: Ah yes I was dumb. I think it would be best for you to edit the reference in your answer, then I can award the bounty!